# Error during installing of module in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am currently encountering an error in Odoo. I am using Odoo v.10 and I am looking for loan management module for FREE and I found a module in lower version which is 8 and when I'm installing the module, it gives me an error. Why is this?

[image: Here's the log error]

but I checked it and the model name is perfectly declared on its dunder init and the views are declared on its manifest or dunder openerp.

[image: account.loan.proof.type, model name]

[image: my views.xml]

[image: my dunder init]

[image: the dunder openerp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In odoo v10 using new api. So you must be upgrade that module v8 to v10. As per your screen shot this code are written in V8 and using old API. In v10, osv package is not available, also i think you don't use any **cr, self, context** type parameter in funtion, also don't use **self.pool.get()**. You should be use **self.env[]** for v10.

Answer (score 0):

you have to upgrade your addon from old api to new api. please read this guidelines and it will help you.

[odoo new api guidlines](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)